# Update UI On RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I've used Background workers lots of times in the passed to use the DoWork to go and get the data and then the WorkerComplete which I believe runs on the UI thread to update the UI. But in the way I have it working at the minute I keep getting a cross-thread error?

Heres what I have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 Public Form1()
 {
 }

    BackgroundWorker CheckPopUps;
    DataSet Popups = new DataSet();
    public void Rotate()
    {
        CheckPopUps = new BackgroundWorker();
        CheckPopUps.DoWork += CheckPopUps_DoWork;
        CheckPopUps.RunWorkerCompleted += CheckPopUps_RunWorkerCompleted;
        CheckPopUps.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

           void CheckPopUps_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable Pops1 = SharedTools.DataProcedures.Popup_GetListToPop(2, ScreenName, "Interviews");
        if (Pops1.Rows.Count > 1) { Popups.Tables.Add(Pops1.Copy()); }

    }


 void CheckPopUps_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataTable myTable in Popups.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow myRow in myTable.Rows)
            {
                PopUp Pop = new PopUp();
                Pop.SetDetails(myRow);
                this.Controls.Add(Pop);
  //Error occurs on this line ^
  //Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Pop` should be lowecase `pop` since it is a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

When `RunWorkerAsync` it will look at the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` and, if not null, use that as the mechanism to marshal the event handlers to the UI thread.  It doesn't magically know how to run code in the UI thread; it needs to be given some means from somewhere.

This means that `Rotate` needs to be called from the UI thread, since that's where you call `RunWorkerAsync`.  You're apparently calling it from a non-UI thread.

Comment: @Ssc456 You shouldn't have multiple UI threads.  If you do you're only ever setting yourself up for a world of hurt.  Use a single UI thread in all applications at all times.  Then it becomes a non-issue.  That said, if you're calling it from the wrong UI-thread then yes, it would cause an issue.  You can't access a control from a different thread than the one that created it; it doesn't matter if that thread happens to be the thread that created a bunch of other controls.

Comment: Thanks, if i'm honest this seems to be going a little over my head. To my knowledge I don't (shouldn't) have more than 1 UI thread. The UserControl that Calls Rotate was created on the Main Form's UI thread. Then it calls Rotate on the tick event of a timer that to my knowledge should be on the main UI Thread?

Comment: @Ssc456 There are many types of timers, some will tick in the UI thread, some won't.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: @Ssc456 I can only guess without seeing what you're doing.  For whatever reason, `Rotate` isn't being called from the UI thread.  Possibly you're using another timer, perhaps the timer is mis-configured and as such isn't firing its event in the UI thread, perhaps you're explicitly doing something somewhere to run the code in another thread, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should only get a cross-thread error if you call `Rotate` on a thread other than the UI thread.  The `RunWorkerCompleted` handler will not *necessarily* run on the UI thread - it actually runs on the `SynchornizationContext` that is current when `RunWorkerAsync` is called.  This means if you call `Rotate` on the UI thread, it should happen on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you Reed, this may be my issue, Rotate is called by another UserControl in Form1 using:   ((Form1)this.ParentForm).Rotate();

Answer (score -1):

I have these extension methods defined which allow me to call UI elements from any thread

```
public delegate void EmptyHandler();
public delegate void ParamHandler(params object[] args);
public static void SafeCall(this System.Windows.Forms.Control control, ParamHandler method, params object[] args)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(method, args);
    }
    else
    {
        method(args);
    }
}
public static void SafeCall(this System.Windows.Forms.Control control, EmptyHandler method) 
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(method);
    }
    else
    {
        method();
    }
}
```

To be used for example as

```
progress.SafeCall(() => progress.Value=100);
```

In your case it would be

```
var pop = new PopUp();
...
this.SafeCall( ()=> this.Controls.Add(pop) );
```